# Passing a function from useReducer state to the component that needs it

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-select

Im still new to React useReducer and trying to make my reducer with handleChange function for state changes and passing the handler to the child component(react-select components) so I can change my state in parent component on selection of the options from drodown menu in child component and apply the selection as a filter to an array that I fetched from server. Since change handler is not a pure function, should I choose some external library for that and since dispatch method is used to trigger state change should i declare it in parent or pass it to child component? Here is the example code:

```
//Code I want to transform to useReducer
//Parent component
const export default parentComponent = () => {

const [selectedMake, setSelectedMake] = useState();

const handleMakeChange = select => {
setSelectedMake(select.value);
};

return (
<>
<MakeFilter fetchedArray={fetchedArray} handleMakeChange={handleMakeChange} colourStyles ={colourStyles}>
</>
)
}

//Child component( Select component and passed in props too it are all coming from //imported react-select library)
const MakeFilter = ({ fetchedArray, handleMakeChange, colourStyles }) => {
  const distinctBy = (arr, f) => {
    return arr.filter((a, i) => arr.findIndex(b => f(a) === f(b)) === i);
  };

  const options = fetchedArray.map(car => {
    return {
      value: car.make,
      label: car.make,
    };
  });

  const distinctOptions = distinctBy(options, car => car.value);

  return (
    <>
      <Select
        components={{ IndicatorSeparator: () => null }}
        placeholder='Marke'
        className='select-placeholder'
        styles={colourStyles}
        options={distinctOptions}
        onChange={handleMakeChange}
        isSearchable={false}
        theme={theme => ({
          ...theme,
          borderRadius: 0,
          colors: {
            ...theme.colors,
            primary25: 'grey',
            primary: 'grey',
          },
        })}
      />
    </>
  );
};

export default MakeFilter;
```

Should I write an action for every filter field in switch statement like case: 'SET_MAKE', case: 'SET_MODEL' because I have more than one react-select component?

**Update**

Implemented dispatch in handler function, but how do I access event.value to replace the initial state of make?
Here is the code:

```
export const INITIAL_STATE = {
  make: null,
}

export const carsReducer = (INITIAL_STATE, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case 'onChange':
      return {
        ...INITIAL_STATE,
        make: select.value,
      };
    default:
      throw new Error(`Unknown action type: ${action.type}`);
  }
```

Im really sorry for these noob questions, just cant get the birds eye view on this hook.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use `dispatch` to set the value in your parent onChange:

```
function reducerFn(state, action) {
  switch (action.type) {
     case "onChange":
       // Assign input value to state on change
       return {...state, [action.event.target.name]: action.event.target.value};
    default:
      throw Error("Unknown action " + action.type);
  }
}

function Parent() {
  const [state, dispatch] = useReducer(reducerFn);

  const onChange = (event) => {
    dispatch({type: "onChange", event});
  };

  return <MakeFilter handleMakeChange={onChange} />
}
```

Comment: Updated the question. Trying to access event.value in reducer function as a replacement of the initial state but cant since they both are undefined in reducerFn.

Comment: Found this thread with the answer how to pass data to dispatcher by adding it to the state but, in my case Im passing this function just to access the value of selected field and making it parent state. Is there any workaround to my case? Here is the thread: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60580240/using-usereducer-to-dispatch-action-from-one-child-component-and-update-state-in

Comment: In your update you can access `action.event` if you have used a similar event handler like my example. An action normally is an object having a `type` and optional additional properties like  `event` in this case. The event is the actual change event of the input element. Ive added an example for reducer.

Comment: Explained better than 50 minutes of random youtubers and React docs. Kudos to you for helping a noob(me).